# Java BigInteger bitLength() method ignores leading 0-bits

Tags: java, encryption, biginteger

Java : jre1.8.0_45

I finished debugging my Elliptic Curve class and in logging all characteristics of the keys I also log the BIT length of the keys (which with Elliptic Curve is not always an even number of bits).

I display the bit length of the Keys via a BigInteger:

```
ECPrivateKey oPK=generate the key ...
BigInteger oBI=oPK.getS(); 
MetaLogBook.debug("Key Size in Bits :"+oBI.bitLength()+
                "\nRaw Key Hex      : 0x"+oBI.toString(16)).toUpperCase()+"\n"+);
```

While the key is always correctly represented and ciphering works fine, the bit size however fluctuates.  Many times it is correct (571) but from time to time it is a few bits off.

So I started to generate AES-256 keys and I noticed that they are often 256 bits but also from time to time a few bits off. So it had nothing to do with the odd number of bits in Elliptic Curve.

After a long search I THINK I found an explanation, or at least a beginning of an explanation, but I don't know if this is INTENDED or a Java Bug.

When I saw that this 64 bytes hex (32 byte AES 256 bit key) had a bit length of 254 displayed in stead of 256 I could draw a conclusion.

> 0x27006F59EA138FE01FBE1F554253DBDD84D73719E77088907357C6FA6B60F170

The last nibble is 0, so if trailing 0-bits would not be counted then I would have been at least 4 bits short in the bitLength() and I was only 2 bits short.

Then it occurred to me that the first nibble of my key started with a 2 or binary 0010. So I figured that the BigInteger.bitLength() didn't count the LEADING zero BITS. I repeated this a number of times and the behaviour seems consistent (normally I think everyone can reproduce this).

I would like to know if this is the WANTED behaviour of BigInteger.bitLength() or if this could possibly be a bug. I wouldn't have asked the question if it weren't that I assume that many crypto code in Java may rely on BigInteger (including providers) and I cannot imagine they wouldn't have ran into this problem.

TIA

Comment: Leading zero bits are not part of the value. There is no limit to how many there could be, and no mathematical reason to count any of them.

Comment: EJP, I agree with the 'mathematical' reason. However in ciphering it is very important that leading 0-bits are present at the Most Significant Bit side or the ciphered result completely changes. Fortunately the ECC and AES ciphers seem not to rely on BigInteger to measure the real bit lenght of the key (that is leading zeroes included). I think the method should have been called significantBitLenght() the way it functions now but OK for Math is doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working as intended and as documented.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#bitLength--):

> Returns the number of bits in the minimal two's-complement representation of this BigInteger, excluding a sign bit. For positive BigIntegers, this is equivalent to the number of bits in the ordinary binary representation.

Note the "minimal" part here - for example the decimal value 5 can be represented as 00000000000000000000000000101 or 101... but 101 is the minimal representation, so the bit length is 3.

Comment: I understand, so I need to look at the underlying bytes and count the leading zeroes and then add them to the bitLength() myself to obtain the real bitLength (because for me 0 is as well a bit as 1 and bit length should include both). However I understand you Documentation explanation. It doesn't return the bit Length but the minimal two's compliment bit length. Kind of unexpected but OK. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Danny: I'm not sure how you're getting the "underlying bytes" to start with - note that BigInteger.toByteArray returns the minimum number of bytes required...

Comment: Jon, that is why I switched to AES Keys, there I can do: BigInteger oBI=new BigInteger(1,this.oSymmetricKey.getEncoded()); So I have the byte[] array and the BigInteger. With Elliptic Curve I don't because it is getS() that returns the private Key as a BI.