# Java BigInteger is giving In-Correct result

Tags: java, java-8, biginteger

From this post [Bit Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31918442/java-biginteger-bitlength-method-ignores-leading-0-bits)  what I understood is `bitlength()` will gives you

> the number of bits in the minimal two's-complementrepresentation of
>   this BigInteger

However when I ran the following program output is 
**0** I am expecting this output to be **1** as number **0** is represented by one bit, I am confused here please help

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int l = BigInteger.valueOf(0L).bitLength();
        System.out.println(l);
    }
}
```

Comment: The key word is *minimal*. You don't need any bits to represent zero.

Comment: But sir, how is zero represented then :( It must require something deep down in memory

Comment: 0 is the bit sequence "". Having the human convention representing it as "0" is an exceptional case. Normally preceding zeroes are stripped.

Comment: "how is zero represented then" - well that depends on the data type. Of course `BigInteger` takes up some memory but from a _logical_ point of view 0 is "nothing" and "nothing" has no length.

Comment: awesome, got it now, thanks a lot ..veterans :)

Comment: If you want to get the bit length as in "do I need 8, 16,32,64 ... bits to represent that value?" then you could do `toByteArray() * 8` or (as per the source code of that method) you could calculate the length in bytes as `int byteLen = bitLength()/8 + 1;` without actually copying the array. Note that the JavaDoc on `toByteArray()` states: "The array will contain the minimum number of bytes required to represent this BigInteger"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#bitLength--):

> Computes `(ceil(log2(this < 0 ? -this : this+1)))`.

Since `this >= 0`, it computes `ceil(log2(1))`, `log_anything(1) == 0`, and `ceil(0) == 0`.

---

You ask [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56882441/java-biginteger-is-giving-in-correct-result/56882510#comment100312664_56882441) "how is zero represented then :( It must require something deep down in memory".

A `BigInteger` representing zero, clearly, does have some representation in memory. But you can think of it like an array of some notional type, `bit`, i.e. `bit[]`. Zero could be represented by the zero-length array `new bit[]{}` (but it could also be `new bit[]{0}`, `new bit[]{0, 0}` etc).

It's fine for an array to have zero length in Java (it's specifically called an [*empty array*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-10.html) in the spec). Such an array has zero elements, but it has a non-zero size in memory, because it needs to store the length of the array somewhere (and other things for housekeeping).

`bitLength()` is the *minimal* length of this array. A zero length doesn't mean that the array takes no space in memory, just that its elements take no *additional* space.

Comment: Note that [the recent documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#bitLength()) clears any doubt by stating explicitly: “*For zero this method returns 0*”. Since this method is not supposed to say anything about the memory needed for this `BigInteger`, anything said about the memory is rather distracting. Whether a `BigInteger`’s internal representation truly uses an empty array for a zero bitcount or not, is an implementation detail. E.g. a bitcount of one or 32 makes no difference to the memory consumption with this implementation.